# Does SQL Server share sessions?

Tags: sql-server, concurrency, sql-server-2014

In SQL Server 2014 I open 3 sessions on the same database. In the first session I run `Update Statistics A`. I time this to take around 1 minute.

In my 2nd and 3rd sessions I run an `Update Statistics B` (one at a time). Each takes about 1 minute as well.

I then run `Update Statistics A` on session 1, and `Update Statistics B` on session 2, both at the same time. Each query finishes in around 1 minute, as expected.

I then run `Update Statistics A` on window 1, and `Update Statistics B` on window 3, both at the same time. Each query takes close to 2 minutes now.

I checked sp_who2 and can see 3 distinct sessions here. What could be a possible cause for this?

Also, when I check the query status I noticed in the scenario where I run queries on windows 1 and 3, one status is always running while the other is either runnable or suspended. In the other scenario where I run on windows 1 and 2 both are always running.

Comment: What software are you using to "open 3 windows on the same database"? Do you understand the difference between connections and sessions in SQL Server? Do you know about SQL Server's Dynamic Management Views, like `sys.dm_exec_sessions` and `sys.dm_exec_connections`? Do you know [how sessions and connections fit together](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-connections-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)?

Comment: not previously but I do see they are 2 distinct sessions and connections.

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are always different. You can see the SPID in the bottom of the SQL Server Management Studio Window or you can do a:

```
SELECT @@SPID
```

to see the session number. SQL Server is a multiple access simultaneous system which manages it own sessions and threads. The number of active sessions is dependent on what the sessions are doing and long a session has been doing something and how much resources the machine that SQL Server is running on - typically more memory/CPUS will result in more active simultaneous sessions. Of course there could be a few heavy sessions that use all the resource of the machine.

Sessions are somewhat isolated but depending on the locking being used the sessions are somewhat, or very, isolated from each other. SQL Server will decide when to temporarily suspend a session so other sessions can have a turn using the CPU/Memory. If a whole bunch of sessions are all updating the same table there may be contention that will slow SQL Server down. What you are asking is how long does it take to drive a 100 miles. Depends of course.

If you have three sessions doing the same thing SQL Server will not fold up the three actions into one. It will do each one (simultaneously if possible) or serially.

Comment: Sorry, I was probably not being clear enough. Basically I have two sessions that are always sharing resource regardless of what table I am updating statistics on. I can see that they keep alternating between running and runnable so there must be some kind of locking going on here. There is some underlying lock only between these 2 sessions, i can run 2 different queries in parallel without this issue if I swap out one of these sessions for another.

Comment: SQL Server has gotten really good at maintaining statistics and most people only check statistics once a day and unless a table has a lot (sic) of inserts and updates the Statistics stay accurate (produce good query plans) so its unnecessary to keep rebuilding statistics.  The default behavior is row locking. However some operations require may induce SQL Server to kick off table locking. There are also other locks that occur such as schema locks and intent locks. A really good introduction to locking is Kalen Delaney's book SQL Server Concurrency: Locking, Blocking, and Row Versioning,

Comment: I am almost certain it is not row or table locking, it doesn't matter which tables I am trying to Update Statistics on. Also as soon as I move one of the queries to another session this no longer occurs. Seems like SQL server has some kind of restriction that allows only one of these 2 sessions to be executing at once

Comment: I have never heard about such a restriction. I would run in another session a query to see what locks are being taken. Please see a good query from here: https://aboutsqlserver.com/2012/04/05/locking-in-microsoft-sql-server-part-13-schema-locks/